# MongoDB automatic failover not working for second time

Tags: java, mongodb, grails

I am using MongoDB `compile "org.grails.plugins:mongodb:3.0.1"`. Currently, the automatic failover is working only for first time when i kill MongoDB primary instance. In this case, the secondary becomes Primary and the application is able to read the data. But when i kill again the newly elected Primary and the previously killed is UP now. It means again i have one Primary. The second time failover is not working through MongoDB driver in this case. It throws the `MongoServerSelectionException`. It's been more than 5 days i am not able to find the solution. Below is my java code

```
static{
            FileInputStream fis=null;

        try {
            /**** Get database ****/
            // if database doesn't exists, MongoDB will create it for you
            fis=new FileInputStream(GRMConstants.MONGODB_PROPERTY_FILE);
            properties=new Properties();
            properties.load(fis);

            String[] host=properties.getProperty("MONGODB_SERVER_ADDRESS").split(",");
            List<ServerAddress> server= new ArrayList<ServerAddress>();
            for(int i=0;i<host.length;i++){
            server.add(new ServerAddress(host[i],Integer.valueOf(properties.getProperty("MONGODB_PORT"))));
            }

            mongo = new MongoClient(server);
            databaseName=properties.getProperty("MONGO_DATABASE");
            //get database
            database=mongo.getDB(databaseName);     
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            log.error("UnknownHostException in MongoDBUtil while initilizing MongoDb server ...",ex);
        } catch (MongoException ex) {
            log.error("MongoException in MongoDBUtil while initilizing MongoDb server ...",ex);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("IOException in MongoDBUtil while initilizing MongoDb server ...",e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception in MongoDBUtil while initilizing MongoDb server ...",e);
        } finally {
            if(fis != null) {
                try {
                    fis.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log.error("Exception in MongoDBUtil while closing the input stream...", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But if restart the server, the problem is solved. It seems the driver is not able to detect the changes after killing instances. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: how many nodes you have? which mongodb version? what does your mongodb host configuration looks like?

Comment: I have three nodes. one primary, one secondary and one arbiter. i have mongoDB 2.6 and my configuration is `MONGODB_SERVER_ADDRESS=192.168.121.56,192.168.121.58 MONGODB_PORT=27017`. Also, i have noticed the error while killing instance `Expecting replica set member from set 'mongoReplica', but found one from set 'null'.  Removing grm2:27017 from client view of cluster`. Thanks